# scons on win32: debugging SConstruct with pdb

Tags: python, windows, scons, pdb

I'm trying to debug a SConstruct file that's failing deep deep into some obscure function, and I want to step through the code. This is what I tried to do, and failed:

```
$ python -m pdb `which scons.py`
> c:\python27\scripts\scons.py(26)<module>()
-> __revision__ = "src/script/scons.py 5357 2011/09/09 21:31:03 bdeegan"
(Pdb) b SConstruct:10
***  'SConstruct' not found from sys.path
(Pdb) import sys, os
(Pdb) sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
(Pdb) b SConstruct:10
***  'SConstruct' not found from sys.path
(Pdb)
```

If I rename SConstruct to SConstruct.py, it succeeds to set a breakpoint, but of course it doesn't work, because "scons" loads SConstruct, not SConstruct.py.
Any way to force python to put a breakpoint there?

I'm running this from a msys bash console on a Win7 system.
Python version:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some tips on the [Debugging SCons wiki page](https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/DebuggingScons). Specifically:

```
scons --debug=pdb <args...>
# from the wiki example: you can set a breakpoint on a file relative to sys.path
(Pdb) b SCons/Tool/msvc.py:158 
# you can set a breakpoint in the SConstruct file with the full path
(Pdb) b /Users/me/code/project/SConstruct:10
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I guess I found some workaround and called it a day. Anyway, I just tried this suggestion under windows, and it seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my ubuntu setup for some reason instead, but maybe I'm doing something wrong... and anyway, the question was mostly about windows.

Comment: That link is dead.